# Expand DropDown List on click

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a `dropdownlist` which has a single element to start with, for every single user.

The element name is `'Standard'`. Since its a single element ,click on the dropdownlist doesn't expand the dropdownlist in the downwards direction.

Is there any method so that I can expand the dropdownlist on the click, even if it has a single element in it.

I know this question doesn't make much sense, but my clients are interested in something like this.

Any work arounds, any manipulations, any kind of `CSS` would work.

Any pointers would be highly appreciated. And yes my application is in `ASP.NET`.

Code:

```
<div style="float: left; vertical-align: middle;">
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropDownListView" Width="100px" runat="server"   CssClass="DropDownStyleSmallWidth">
</asp:DropDownList>
&nbsp;</div>
```

Code Behind:

```
    public void PopulateOtherViews()
    {
        SaveReportViewFilter<ReportFilterBase> newObj = new SaveReportViewFilter<ReportFilterBase>();
        ViewColumnOptions vwobj = new ViewColumnOptions();
        newObj.UserName = vwobj.Page.User.Identity.Name;
        SaveReportView<ReportFilterBase> obj2 = new SaveReportView<ReportFilterBase>();
        DataTable dt = obj2.GetSaveReportViewFromDataBase(newObj);
        dropDownListView.DataSource = dt;
        dropDownListView.DataTextField = dt.Columns[0].ToString();
        dropDownListView.DataValueField = dt.Columns[0].ToString();
        dropDownListView.DataBind();

    }
```

Basically my dropdownlist is in a usercontrol, which is populated on the Page_Load.

Comment: why dnt you add `<asp:ListItem Value="0">--Select--</asp:ListItem>`and now on click you will see your other values, also  post your HTML markup  for easy understanidng for reader

Comment: I am not allowed to use Select or Choose kind of listitem...My app is such that Standard is default for everybody and people can create their own elements by clicking on some image buttons which I have provided..These elements will be added to the dropdownlist dynamically..Hence if a user creates his own element and then click on the dropdownlist, it will expand.

Answer (score 1):

This code will expand the `DropDown` as `ListBox`.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
      $('#Standard').click(function (){
         $(this).attr("size","1"); 
      });
    });
</script>
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Mayank..how does this code work..does it mean that it will take the id of Standard element and on the click of that it will try to expand the dropdownlist...Do I need to add an onclick event for the dropdownlist in which I can call the above piece of code??

Comment: i have edited my answer...Just use the above code in `<script>` section and it will work on `Standard` element's `click` event.

Comment: Umm..I am working on a Legacy code with ASP.NET 2.0 controls..my bad actually..the compiler doesn't detect $ and sends an error that its not a defined function..can you alter your code to be a normal JavaScript one? TIA

Comment: Just copy the answer now and put this right before end of `<body>` tag in your `HTML` it will work.

Comment: Buddy,you know I really appreciate your efforts but I am not allowed to use jQuery in my project...

Answer (score 0):

Here i added a single item list to my dropdownlist, and on click its expands to downward as what you asked for,
Also if its blank it will expand downwards.

**Html Markup :**

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
      <asp:ListItem>ABC</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
```

**ScreenShot :**

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: HI Satinder, yeah I can see that even an empty dropdownlist expands below, but in my case I am binding the dropdownlist via a datatable taking values from DB..i knw it doesn't make sense, but still I aint able to expand the ddl when I have only one value in it i.e Standard..any views??

Comment: @Anurag: Pls post your code, for better understandable, might be their is issue while populating dropdownlist

Comment: @Satinder..have edited the question and added code bits...my app uses ASP.NET 2.0 controls..i cnt help that.. :)

Comment: @Anurag: your code seems perfect, you have done proper binding , if works for me dnt knw why you facing this issue,

Comment: I found out the reason..I am using IE 10..thats why..I tried this is IE9..the dropdownlist expands...Thanks for your replies anyways...

Comment: @Anurag: Good you solved it. well their a saying `IE developed while their developer are drunken`  Lol